# AEM clean install -PautoInstallPackage with Jenkins in docker

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins, aem

**Situation** :

- I set up Jenkins with docker, to install package on AEM instance.
- In my pom.xml, 'targetURL' of profile 'autoInstallPackage' is "http://localhost:4502/crx/packgmr/service.jsp".

**Problem** :

- When I set 'targetURL' with IP address, it works.
- When I set 'targetURL' with 'localohost', it fails.

**What I want to do** :

- Run 'autoInstallPackage' targetURL with 'localhost', not IP address.

**I guess the cause is this** (not sure) :

- Jenkins is running inside docker, so the docker container could be considered as 'localhost'.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is right. The localhost exists only inside the container.

To bypass this behaviour you can run the docker image as so:

```
docker run --network host --name jenkins your_jenkins_image
```

The `--network host` param will cause the docker container to use the dns of the host machine (the machine running docker).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your way but it didn't work for me. I've been searching why and I just found the reason : '--network host' doesn't work for Windows. I'm using docker on Windows, so I think I should set up jenkins without docker.

Comment: But your answer was very helpful, so thank you a lot.